# How to create a button in Kotlin that opens a new activity (Android Studio)?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

Hello I'm making an app using Android Studio and the Kotlin language and am having trouble getting my button to open a new activity. I have the button created in my xml file but I can't find the KOTLIN syntax of how to declare it in MainActivity.kt and how to create the OnClicklistener that would take me to the new activity. I have the new activity defined in the manifest as well I think I just need syntax help on how to actually switch from MainActivity.kt to secondActivity.kt. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The same way do it in Kotlin like as Java. Maybe you need to learn android first rather than kotlin.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can add `onclick` event listener like below.

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(view: View): Unit {
        // Handler code here.
        val intent = Intent(context, DestActivity::class.java);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
})
```

Or you can use simplified form

```
   button1.setOnClickListener {
    // Handler code here.
    val intent = Intent(context, DestActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, if I copy paste the above code into my MainActivity.kt file pretty much the entire thing is covered in error messages saying that startActivity, Intent, and context are all unresolved references and that final/intent have variables expected. It also says on the first line that a member declaration is expected. Any idea what is wrong?

Edit: On top of that, if I use the simplified form it says that the function declaration no longer has a name.

Comment: I assumed that your button variable name is `button1` and `context` variable has the activity context (else just use `this` or `YourClassName.this` ).

Comment: add this code inside onCreate() and after you get the reference of button1 via findViewById()

Comment: thank you very much for the help so far, I still have a few issues though, I have gotten the reference of button1 and put everything inside of onCreate() but the line
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, secondActivity.class);
says that final is still an unresolved reference and expects a variable, that Intent expects a variable (am I supposed to use secondActivity as the intent here or something?), that "new" is an unresolved reference, and that secondActivity is an unexpected token.

Comment: Thank you! Down to one final error saying that java is an unresolved reference in "secondActivity::class.java", I also tried replacing it with class.kotlin but that doesn't seem to do the trick either.

Comment: class names are case sensitive

Comment: "secondActivity" is how I named my second one so I don't think it should be a capitalization issue.

Comment: Is that file named same?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/zQGi9
This is a picture of what I have which might be helpful, the file name of the other activity is the same yes.

Answer (score 6):

Button in layout xml file

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_start_new_activity"
            android:text="New Activity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

For declaring it in the [Kotlin](https://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin-tutorial/) Activity file

```
var btn_new_activity = findViewById(R.id.btn_start_new_activity) as Button
```

Set [Onclicklistener](https://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin-android/set-onclicklistener-button-kotlin-android/) to the button, to start new activity when button is clicked

```
    btn_new_activity.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(context, NewActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Reference: [Android Studio Tutorial](http://www.androidstudiotutorial.com) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7AcIGyugR7M

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use the Anko - extension for Kotlin https://github.com/Kotlin/anko. 
It let you use intent(and more other things) the shortest way. In your case it`ll be:

```
button {
        onClick { startActivity<SecondActivity>() }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I will look into this as well, I would like to figure out how to do it the original way at first but I will for sure look into that for later projects. Cheers.

Comment: It is deprecated. Use [splitties](https://github.com/LouisCAD/Splitties)

Answer (score 2):

```
// In your method `fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)` add this.

    your_btn_id.setOnClickListener{

                val intent = Intent(this, yourpagename::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

// till now if it doesn't work then, check if these two files are added or not,

    import android.content.Intent
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_otp.*
```

// Hope that it would work.

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin**

Make sure the item is inside the `OnCreate` method.
Edit the `XML` file (*res/layout* folder) and create button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Press me"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    />
```

Next is main activity class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener {
           
           val intent = Intent(context, NewActivity::class.java)
           startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a generic method to launch any Activity

```
  inline fun<reified T> launchActivity(){
    val intent = Intent(this, T::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

And can be use like

```
 button1.setOnClickListener {
      launchActivity<AnyActivity>()
}
```

To get More details about reified [Go to Here](https://blog.mindorks.com/what-are-reified-types-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare your button in the main activity as below:

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And in the clicklistener start the new activity:

```
override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        val intent = Intent(this, activity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add first `id 'kotlin-android-extensions'` inside of plugins in build.gradle.
after that in OnCreate
Button.setOnClickListener {
}